# Unable to make holes using boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am pulling teeth trying to get these cylinders to create holes in my movie reel object. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or what settings I should have...can't seem to get to work with any tutorial.

Here's the .blend file:

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39092

Comment: I can't understand what is wrong but I get strange results, using meshes from that file, even importing them in a new empty file. Some  cylinder at least have a negative scale which is bad for booleans, but there 's something more weird, imho. Which version are you using, and do you know which version created them?

Comment: @lakerice, it's probably less effort to start these shapes from scratch. The  thing you need to remember is that Boolean Operations (Currently) still need to happen between 'watertight' objects. (Objects with volume)

Comment: @zeffii I tried also to check with 3d printing toolbox, jsut 2 shapes (the big disk to be holed, and one cylinder): it shows just overhang faces, but that is not a problem unless really 3d printing.

Comment: As you can see I am new to this program lol.  I didn't realize my shapes weren't watertight and connected.  I had the feeling I was making a lot of mistakes trying to piece different objects together manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your file is that you have a lot of disjoint geometry and non volume geometry.

Observing a small section of the model shows a problem: A, B, and C are disjoint. (Not attached to eachother) and they therefor don't form a watertight (Manifold) volume. Also B and C even have Polygon *normals*  that go in opposite directions. Which you can tell by the color differences in the mesh. Purple vs Grey.

[image]

I'm sure if you study the model further, or come back to it when you have more experience with the Boolean Modifier you will see immediately all kinds of things that make it impossible to do what you are trying. I suggest a different approach, it's easier I think.

---

Here's a demonstration of what my approach would be to this. Use the Screw Modifier and a *profile* as the rotation shape. A benefit of this is you can easily change the number of vertices on the circumference of the object, by changing the 'Steps' value.

[image]

I've also used the Array Modifier to make a radial array, this arrays an object (The extruded Circle) around a fixed point (an Empty). The Empty's rotation influences the rotation of the repeated object.

[image]

Then finally you can add the boolean modifier and hide the Circle object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Zeffii.  It really is appreciated.  I've been looking at these instructions and what you did in the file, trying to figure out how you did this step by step.  I see you started with a circle to make the reel and used the screw modifier, but how did you get it to be solid and 3d?  And how did you get that ridge around the outer region.  Sorry if I'm missing obvious things...I'm new to Blender.

Comment: that's OK lakerice, you'll understand these things faster than you think. I'll update the answer. But in the meantime here is the short instructions to get a cylinder.  Add a Circle -> change to Edit Mode -> Select all Vertices -> press F. (this fills the verts, and makes polygon). -> Select the polygon and press E to extrude, moving the mouse will increase the Extrusion.

Comment: you can also just add a Cylinder Mesh.

Comment: Thanks that helped.  However, now I am trying to do what you did in the centre of the reel, but when I use a second boolean modifier in the plane object to difference of circle.001 it makes the entire reel disappear.  Basically I'm trying to get the same holes duplicated but scaled down to the centre of the reel.  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/39111